# PyParsing: parseaction called multiple

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am a beginner with pyparsing but have experience with other parsing environments.
On my first small demo project I encountered a strange behavior of parsing actions: Parse action of base token (`ident_simple`) is called twice for each token of `ident_simple`.

```
import io, sys
from pyparsing import *

def pa_ident_simple(s, l, t):
    print('ident_simple: ' + str(t))

def pa_ident_combined(s, l, t):
    print('ident_combined: ' + str(t))

def make_grammar():
    number = Word(nums) 

    ident_simple = Word( alphas, alphanums + "_" )
    ident_simple.setParseAction(pa_ident_simple)

    ident_combined = Combine(ident_simple + Literal('.') + ident_simple)
    ident_combined.setParseAction(pa_ident_combined)

    integer = number

    elems = ( ident_combined | ident_simple | integer)

    grammar = OneOrMore(elems) + StringEnd()

    return grammar


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp_str = "UUU FFF.XXX GGG"

    grammar = make_grammar() 

    print (inp_str, "--->", grammar.parseString( inp_str ))
```

For 'ident_combined' token it looks good: Parseaction is called once for each sub token 'ident_simple' and once for combined token.

I believe that the combined token is the problem: Parseaction of 'ident_simple' is called only once if 'ident_combined' is removed.

Can anybody give me a hint how to combine tokens correctly?

Thanks for any help

**Update**: When playing around I took the class "Or" instead of "MatchFirst".

```
elems = (  ident_combined ^ ident_simple ^ integer)
```

This showed a better behavior (in my opinion).

Output of original grammar (using "MatchFirst"):

```
ident_simple: ['UUU']
ident_simple: ['UUU']
ident_simple: ['FFF']
ident_simple: ['XXX']
ident_combined: ['FFF.XXX']
ident_simple: ['GGG']
ident_simple: ['GGG']
UUU FFF.XXX GGG ---> ['UUU', 'FFF.XXX', 'GGG']
```

Output of modified grammar (using "Or"):

```
ident_simple: ['UUU']
ident_simple: ['FFF']
ident_simple: ['XXX']
ident_combined: ['FFF.XXX']
ident_simple: ['GGG']
UUU FFF.XXX GGG ---> ['UUU', 'FFF.XXX', 'GGG']
```

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe. I see pa_ident_simple called twice for 'UUU', (first when trying to match the ident_combined, then again when matching ident_simple), once for 'FFF' and 'XXX', then pa_ident_combined is called for 'FFF.XXX', then pa_ident_simple is called for 'GGG' twice (again, once when trying to parse an ident_combined, then again when successfully parsing an ident_simple).  I get the same whether is Combine is there or not. Could you post your output?

Comment: I was thinking, that parseActions are called only on a successful match. In my opinion "ident_simple" should be called only once for string 'UUU' ?